# Lots of cakephp warnings in the log

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

i get a lot of warnings in my logs like:
2010-08-24 09:34:01 Warning: Warning (2): mssql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in [C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mssql.php, line 468]
2010-08-24 09:34:01 Warning: Warning (2): mssql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in [C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mssql.php, line 180]
2010-08-24 09:34:01 Warning: Warning (2): mssql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in [C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mssql.php, line 180]

these warnings just overun my log files and make them almost useless.
i looked up the lines and they used the @ sign to suppress these errors like:
@mssql_free_result($this->results);

and still the show up in my log is there anyway to really suppress them without changing the cake code?

**UPDATE:**

ok i looked in to this a bit more
this only happens when I'm not in debug mode

and this is becous in the error handling function fron debugger there
is this:

```
if (error_reporting() == 0 || $code === 2048 || $code === 8192) {
    return;

}
```

and in the normal production error handling:

```
if ($code === 2048 || $code === 8192) {
    return;

}
```

so in production it doesn't check if error_reporting() is suppressed

Comment: Sounds like you have messages that you should *NOT* ignore.

Comment: If this is clearly a reproducible problem you should probably open a ticket for it at http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Errors like that are usually the result of poor database error handling. Assuming a query will succeed and blindly using the returned values from ..._query() functions will cause warnings like that. `mssql_query()` returns a statement handle only if there were results. It will also return `TRUE` if the query succeeded but there were no results, and `FALSE` on error.

Passing true/false in to the later functions (such as `mssql_num_rows()`) will spit out the "not a valid ... resource" errors/warnings, because, well... they aren't handles.

In other words, the error isn't really at the lines indicated in the warnings, it's earlier in the script, wherever the query actually was executed.